Numeric Value / Timestamp Value 'dat' not recognized Snowflake Variant
I have a base table EXTRACT_TABLE which holds data for various tables loaded using COPY INTO.
TABLE_NAME distinguishes data for each table.
The EXTRACT_TABLE is loaded via COPY INTO loading CSV files as JSON. CSV is converted to JSON using OBJECT_CONSTRUCT("C1",$1,"C2",$2.....C300,$300)
Once EXTRACT_TABLE is loaded, data is being split into individual flattened tables with appropriate casting of columns.
My sql's suddenly started failing for multiple table only where C29 was being casted to Number/Timestamp with an error as 'dat' unrecognized.
Now the strange thing is that I did below and I can only see valid values,
select DISTINCT VARIANT_COL:C29
FROM EXRACT_TABLE WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLEA'
-- All valid Numeric Values

But when I do this
select DISTINCT VARIANT_COL:C29::number
FROM EXRACT_TABLE WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLEA'
-- This fails stating Numeric value 'dat' is not recognized

I tried this too,
select DISTINCT VARIANT_COL:C29::number
FROM EXRACT_TABLE WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLEA'
AND VARIANT_COL:C29<>'dat'
--this runs fine

select DISTINCT VARIANT_COL:C29::number
FROM EXRACT_TABLE WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLEA'
AND VARIANT_COL:C29='dat'
--this runs fine but returns no record

select TO_NUMBER(COL1) FROM (
select DISTINCT VARIANT_COL:C29 as col1
FROM EXRACT_TABLE WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLEA'
)
--This also runs fine.
--this runs fine

It's very strange that for all tables which are failing C29 column is the issue and apparently the distinct values of it are all valid.
Anyone faced similar issue with 'dat'

Have you tried a TRY_TO_NUMBER function instead of a ::number?  I suspect you have a value in that field of dat that you are not seeing.  A TRY_TO_NUMBER will return a null for anything that isn't a number and will prevent a failure from occurring.

Apparently TRY_TO_NUMBER OR TRY_CAST doesn't work on Variant Column Attributes

You need to cast the variant attribute to a string first.

Cast to VARCHAR before using TRY_TO_NUMBER for VARIANT data. You can then find the non-numeric data in C29.
select DISTINCT VARIANT_COL:C29
FROM EXTRACT_TABLE WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLEA'
AND TRY_TO_NUMBER(VARIANT_COL:C29::VARCHAR) IS NULL
AND VARIANT_COL:C29 IS NOT NULL

